# Round to the highest power of 2 only binary operations

Tags: java

Given a number x 
 Round to the highest power of 2 which is not higher than x.
I found a simple solution, but I wonder whether it's possible to solve it without "-" operation, using only
 >>, >>>, << and | operations.
Here is my code:

Version 1

```
   public static int maxPowerOf2(int x) 
   {
    x |= x >> 1;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 16;
    return x - (x >> 1);
   }
```

Version 2

```
public static int maxPowerOf2(int x)
{
    int v=x;
    v |= v >> 1;
    v |= v >> 2;
    v |= v >> 4;
    v |= v >> 8;
    v |= v >> 16;
    v= v>>1;

    int m16=~v;
    v=v<<1;
    v=v&m16;

    return v;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "next highest power of 2 which is not higher than x", so for `3`, would it be 2 or 4?

Comment: for 3 is 2, for 17 is 16 etc.

Comment: Where have I seen this before? Oh yeah, [`HashMap.tableSizeFor()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l374).

Comment: Good to see the similar problem in  a real life, but it's a bit different.

Comment: You mean [`Integer.highestOneBit(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit%28int%29)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution only using binary operations.. although it is very close to Version 1:

```
public static int maxPowerOf2(int x) {
    x |= x >> 1;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 16;
    return x ^ (x >> 1);
}
```

In this context, `^` achieves the same thing as arithmetic subtraction

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is identifying the highest bit set in your `x`.
Your code is a variant for doing this on 32-bit values.

The fastest solution would be using a lookup table. Most practically is using a binary search tree. aka:

```
int v = x:
int r = 0;
int shift = 0;
r =     (v > 0xFFFF) ? 1 << 4 : 0; v >>= r;
shift = (v > 0xFF  ) ? 1 << 3 : 0; v >>= shift; r |= shift;
shift = (v > 0xF   ) ? 1 << 2 : 0; v >>= shift; r |= shift;
shift = (v > 0x3   ) ? 1 << 1 : 0; v >>= shift; r |= shift;
r |= (v >> 1);
```

`r` will hold your result.

With longs you would need to add a level using `0xFFFFFFFF`

And please not you may use `^` (XOR) instead of `-`. for avoiding subtraction in your case. (This would not really effect costs, though)

Comment: Thank you. But .. is it C? I mean v > 0xFFFF - boolean right? and not a number

Comment: Ooops, too much C last week. Changed it to conform to java. Thanks for remembering me.